# Cambiar slide de imagen al seleccionar un item de un accordion con Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola estoy trabajando en una pagina web, soy nuevo diseñando paginas web, y mi intención es que al seleccionar una opción de un Accordion con bootstrap (en este caso un equipo) se seleccione la imagen del equipo seleccionado, que se encuentran en un Carousel con todos los equipos usando bootstrap de igual manera.
Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Edit: tratare de explicarme un poco mejor, tengo un accordion con nombres y descripciónes de varios equipos y un carousel con imágenes de esos mismos equipos, ambos están separados, uno en cada columna. Lo que quiero hacer es que al seleccionar la descripción de un equipo desde el accordion, automáticamente se seleccione la imagen en el carousel de dicho equipo. Espero y me haya podido explicar bien. Saludos.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="owl-carousel slide-one-item-alt">
              <img src="images/slide1.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
              <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
              <img src="images/slide3.png" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="custom-direction">
              <a href="#" class="custom-prev">Anterior</a><a href="#" class="custom-next">Siguiente</a>
            </div>

          </div>
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample" align = "justify">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <p class="lead"><span class="text-primary icon-chevron-circle-right"></span> Equipo 1</p>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Descripcion equipo 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                <p class="lead"><span class="text-primary icon-chevron-circle-right"></span> Equipo 2</p>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Descripcion equipo 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                <p class="lead"><span class="text-primary icon-chevron-circle-right"></span> Equipo 3</p>
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
     Descripcion equipo 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan, no me queda del todo claro qué es lo que deseas lograr. A qué te refieres con "se seleccione el equipo seleccionado"? Puedes añadir más detalles editando tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien lo que tienes que controlar el evento shown.bs.collapse del acordeón para cambiar el elemento del carrusel.

Te he puesto un ejemplo en https://jsfiddle.net/b1zmL7ga/

En este ejemplo el carrusel actualiza el acordeón y el acordeón actualiza el carrusel